# Safely update Stripe Custom Connect Account From Browser

Tags: stripe-payments

I have some stripe custom connect accounts that need updating.

We create these stripe connected accounts when a user signs up on our platform, but we don't ask for all of the information until later.

Here's the rub: We need a social security number. (We will be doing taxes later) I know that this goes into `legal_entity`, but the only way to update connected custom accounts is using the `secret_key` on the back end....but I can't let a SSN touch the back end!....Well, I guess that I could, but I didn't want ANY dangerous information to touch our server, EVER. I definitely wouldn't store it, but I worry about that making me liable.

So if I can't use the secret key in the browser, and I can't let the SSN touch the server....what is the correct way to update a connected account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Stripe.js, you can generate Account Tokens that your server can reference when making API calls, just like you would get a card token when making payments.

There are directions on how to get the token and use it to update legal information in the documentation here:

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-tokens#updating

Comment: This is also the correct way for collecting bank account information! Make the token using Stripe.js in the browser, then send the token to the server. Your server can then send that token to Stripe to safely update anything sensitive. Awesome!